# How to show the content of a List in JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I have a *Collection* of type *List* that I want to pass it to a report using *JasperReports* and *iReport* on *NetBeans*, but I can't manage to show the content of the list on the Report.
I don't know how to show the data in the ***Details*** section of the jrxml. What parameter should I use?
The list has Objects of type `Proveedor` (Provider in Spanish) and has variables like name, code, etc.
Here is the code of the method who call to *JasperReports*:

```java
public void generateReport(List<Proveedor> aList){
    String reportName = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\reports\\lista-proveedores.jrxml";
    JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataSource;
    JasperReport jasperReport;
    JasperPrint jasperPrint;

    try{
        //1-I fill the dataSource with the Collection
        dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(aList);

        //2-Compile the XML
        jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportName);

        //3-Fill the report with the datasource
        jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, dataSource);

        //4-Export to PDF and save to disk
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "Proveedores.pdf");

        System.out.println("Finished!");

    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: [Here is](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/datasource/index.html#javabeandatasources) the sample. You should create fields in jrxml file and just use it (add to the band)

Comment: Thanks for the documentation, it was really helpfull!!! :D

Comment: Welcome :)  By the way, you can post the correct solution (as answer) for the future readers